# Remove text from html node with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to delete text from a html node, but keep the inner HTML
Anyone who knows how to do this?

**Example**:

```
<td class="ms-list-addnew">
   <a class="ms-herocl" id="idHPNewDocument"><span>new document</span></a>
   or drag files here
</td>
```

**Needed result** (remove the " or drag files here"):

```
<td class="ms-list-addnew">
   <a class="ms-herocl" id="idHPNewDocument"><span>new document</span></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep what you have, this can work for you. Otherwise you can add a `span` tag around it with an id and remove it.

```
var text = $(".ms-list-addnew").html()
text = text.replace("or drag files here","");
$(".ms-list-addnew").html(text);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if there are event handlers on the other nodes, this method will make you lose them.

Comment: Agreed, @Vivin Paliath's answer is better in that regard.

Comment: Yeah, yours is actually neat. One problem that Vivin's doesn't address is what if you CAN'T replace the floating text with a tag? This happens to be the case with DataTable's "Search:" string in the filter bar.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to put the text in another element (say, a `span`) and use [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
<td class="ms-list-addnew">
   <a class="ms-herocl" id="idHPNewDocument"><span>new document</span></a>
   <span id="dragText">or drag files here</span>
</td>
```

Then:

```
jQuery("#dragText").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/hU7T4/)**

```
$('.ms-list-addnew .ms-herocl')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#idHPNewDocument')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = null;
```